# Run unittest.main() from a python invoke task

Tags: python, python-unittest, pyinvoke

I am trying to run some unittest tests via a [Python Invoke library](http://www.pyinvoke.org/), but my poor knowledge of Python prevents me from doing so.

This is the sample code I have:

my_tests.py

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

tasks.py

```
from invoke import task

@task
def tests(ctx):
    main()

@task
def other_task(ctx):
    print("This is fine")

def main():
    import my_tests
    import unittest
    unittest.main(module='my_tests')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is what I get:

```
C:\ittle_projects\invoke_unittest>python my_tests.py
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s

OK

C:\ittle_projects\invoke_unittest>python tasks.py
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK

C:\ittle_projects\invoke_unittest>inv tests
E
======================================================================
ERROR: tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module 'my_tests' has no attribute 'tests'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The tests run fine from my_tests.py and from tasks.py, but when I use invoke stuff breaks. 
How can I make it work or where should I look next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that `unittest.main()` uses the command line arguments your program is called with to determine which tests to run. Since your program is being executed as `inv tests`, the first argument to your program is `tests`, so `unittest` is attempting to run tests for a module name `tests` which does not exist.

You can get around this by popping the last argument (`tests`) from the [system arguments list](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

```
import sys

from invoke import task

@task
def tests(ctx):
    # Pop "tests" off the end of the system arguments
    sys.argv.pop()
    main()

@task
def other_task(ctx):
    print("This is fine")

def main():
    import my_tests
    import unittest
    unittest.main(module='my_tests')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```